# Get file content of a file uploaded using rich:fileUpload

Tags: file-upload, richfaces

So I have an xhtml page that contains the following code:

```
<rich:fileUpload 
            id="uploadReportTemplate" 
            addControlLabel="Add XSLT"                                        
            fileUploadListener="#{manageFeedTypeAction.fileUploadListener}"
            uploadData="#{manageFeedTypeAction.data}"                                                 
            listWidth="63px" listHeight="0px" maxFilesQuantity="1"                        
            immediateUpload="true" acceptedTypes="xsl,xslt" 
            allowFlash="false"
            status="eventQueueFileUpload"                    
            ontyperejected="javascript:Richfaces.showModalPanel('wrongSelectionModal');this.disabled=false">
    <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete" reRender="fileUploadPanel"/>
</rich:fileUpload>
```

I am only allowing the user to upload one file. Once this file has been uploaded, I wish to check if the file contains a certain keyword. How can I check whether the file contains that keyword? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding the following code to the fileUploadListener method being called at `fileUploadListener="#{manageFeedTypeAction.fileUploadListener}"` above:

```
public void fileUploadListener(UploadEvent event) {
    UploadItem item = event.getUploadItem();
    if(item == null || item.getData() == null) {
        LOG.error("Uploaded item is null");
    } else {
        String value = new String(item.getData());
        if(value.toLowerCase().contains("String")) {
            LOG.error("Cannot contain 'String'");
        } else {
            setData(item.getData());
            setFileName(item.getFileName());
        }
    }
}
```